# Load stream from cloudflare to <video> tag

Tags: html, cloudflare

I tried loading a stream from https://iframe.cloudflarestream.com/ to an `<video>` tag but the video player couldn't play.
Is there any way to make it happen?

Here is an example code:

```html
<video class="video-upload" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" src="https://iframe.cloudflarestream.com/hash-codexyzxcvasdpoiuasdfl-asdfasdfjl;k?preload=metadata" id="questionVideob8db400536" controls="true" type="video/mp4" width="640"></video>
```

Comment: I would imagine stuff from `iframe.cloudflarestream.com` is meant to be loaded in an iframe. In other words, it's HTML containing video, not straight video.

Comment: @Ouroborus Indeed. I can play the stream successfully with an <iframe> tag. But now I want to find a way to make the stream work with a <video> tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to play it with a video tag, you must enable mp4 support. You can do this in 2 ways

From API :

[Download videos - Cloudflare Stream Docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/viewing-videos/download-videos/)

> Generate downloadable files
> The downloads API response will include all available download types for the video, the download URL for each type, and the processing status of the download file.

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <API_TOKEN>" \ https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/accounts/<ACCOUNT_ID>/stream/<VIDEO_UID>/downloads
```

From Cloudflare Dashboard:

[image: Cloudflare Stream Dashboard Video Detail]

If you're looking for an easier way [use Cloudflare Stream Player](https://developers.cloudflare.com/stream/viewing-videos/using-the-stream-player/) ( work with iframe)

> Cloudflare provides a customizable web player that can play both on-demand and live video, and requires zero additional engineering work.
>
> Use the code example below, replacing <VIDEO_UID> with the video UID (or signed token and < CODE > with the your unique customer code, which can be found in the [Stream Dashboard](https://dash.cloudflare.com/?to=/:account/stream).

```
<iframe src="https://customer<CODE>.cloudflarestream.com/<VIDEO_UID>/iframe" style="border: none" height="720" width="1280" allow="accelerometer; gyroscope; autoplay; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture;" allowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35214013)

Comment: @AaronMeese Thank you for the information, I corrected the answer this way.